# WordPress: can't change `the_widget` args

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi guys I'm trying to change the `h2` in to `h5` on `the_widget` function that I want to display on the 404 page as helpful link, but it's not working:

```php
<?php
$args = array(
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h5 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h5>'
);
the_widget('WP_Widget_Pages', $args);
?>
```

I've tried the above but nothing is changing.
Can somebody help? I'm new to WordPress. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_slug_widgets_init' );
function theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'my_sidebar_1',
        'id' => 'sidebar_1',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all blog posts.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widgetwrapper">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h5 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h5>',
    ) );
}
```

Comment: I'm not adding them to a sidebar , I'm trying to display them on a 404 page as helpful links

Comment: @Codrin you should add that additional information to your question for context.

Comment: It doesn't literally need to be a sidebar, it's just an area you define (in one of your template files) as a widget container. See the third paragraph on this page: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give woocommerce category and attribute filters a unique div ID because I have two sidebars on on page (one for mobile and one for desktop). After inspecting the wordpress code for a while I realized my woocommerce shop sidebar gets displayed by my themes call to the dynamic_sidebar function of widget.php.

There I wanted to change the widget args, without success until I found the 'dynamic_sidebar_params' filter, into that one I hooked.

```
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'shopSidebarParams', 10, 1); 
function shopSidebarParams($params){
   if($params[0]['widget_id']==='woocommerce_product_categories-2'){
       $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div id="woocommerce_product_categories-2-'. getGUID() . '" class="woocommerce widget_product_categories">';
   }
   return $params; 
}
```